# I want to use portrait option in manifest

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

I want to use only portrait option. But when I write it on manifest like this
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
Android studio shows fault and recommend
screenOrientation="fullSensor" to me.
how can I do only "portrait" option.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways,

Add android:screenOrientation="portrait" for each Activity in Manifest File
Add this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); in each java file.

Answer (score 0):

It suggest you to use "fullSensor" or "unspecified" to have a great experience in chrome OS devices, but if you want to ignore it, just add these lines into manifest tag, under where the package name is mentioned:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore= "LockedOrientationActivity"
```

but consider that on chrome devices the landscape orientation may look buggy.